# How to set a formatter in vscode for HTML and Jinja?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vs code and it has auto formating which is great, however, when I write HTML files and use Jinja or DTL, it formats terribly. How do I either disable formatting for this or change it?

I've installed an extension for formatting called Prettier.

This is what I get:

```
{{ block.super }}

{% endblock styling%} {% block title %} Game {{ game.firs_player }} vs.
{{ game.second_player }} {% endblock title %} {% block content %} This is a
detial page for game {{ game.id }}
{% endblock content %}
```

This is what I want:

````
{% load staticfiles %} 

{% block styling%}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock styling%} 

{% block title %} 
    Game {{ game.firs_player }} vs.{{ game.second_player }} 
{% endblock title %} 

{% block content %} 
    This is a detial page for game {{ game.id }}
{% endblock content %}```
````

Comment: Beautify works whereas Prettier did not for me. (I had BetterJinja installed)

Comment: I posted a great working solution here: [Visual Studio Code and Jinja templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72761998/9152905)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify). It isn't perfect, but it gets the job done.

After you installed it, add this to your `settings.json` file:

```json
"beautify.language": {
        "js": {
            "type": [
                "javascript"
            ],
            "filename": [
                ".jshintrc",
                ".jsbeautifyrc"
            ]
            // "ext": ["js", "json"]
            // ^^ to set extensions to be beautified using the javascript beautifier
        },
        "css": [
            "css",
            "scss"
        ],
        "html": [
            "htm",
            "html",
            "django-html"
        ]
        // ^^ providing just an array sets the VS Code file type
    },
```

Now, it should work with Django template files.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I wasn't able to get Daniel's, beautify solution to work. Maybe because I'm using Prettier globally.

Here's what worked for me:

There's a project called [Unibeautify](https://unibeautify.com/) that seems kind of like a "one ring to rule them all" for tying together personalized settings across different formatters and filetypes.

It has a VS Code extension, [VSCode-Unibeautify](https://github.com/Unibeautify/vscode).

After installing the extension, you need to create a config file and tell VS Code where to find it. You can create and [customize](https://assistant.unibeautify.com/#/setup) your own config if you want to use it for multiple languages, but here's what worked for me for Jinja:

```yaml
# unibeautifyrc.yaml
HTML:
  beautifiers:
    - JS-Beautify
    - Pretty Diff
```

and then, in your vscode settings:

```json
// settings.json
  "unibeautify.defaultConfig": "/PATH/TO/unibeautifyrc.yaml",
  "unibeautify.enabled": true,
  "[jinja-html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Glavin001.unibeautify-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
```

What I've done also, is to associate html files with the Jinja filetype in my project's `settings.json`. This lets you use prettifier for other files, and also other projects where you're not using Jinja. I think you could also make the below `*.html` more specific to your templates directory if you prefer.

```json
// MYPROJECT/.vscode/settings.json
{
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "jinja-html"
  }
}
```

This solution is powered by [JS-Beautify](https://js-beautify.com/) which seems to work well with Jinja and powers Atoms [atom-beautify](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify) extension, also by the same author of Unibeautify, [Glavin001](https://github.com/Glavin001), a beautiful individual.

Comment: The problem I found here is that when it finds e.g an <a/> block sorrouded by an if/else  condition, it puts the "else" inside the <a> block  (tab spaced). But from context, it shouldn't be inside.  The "else" should be in the same level as the "if "